# Undefined Behaviour of atoi function

Tags: c, string, atoi

The following code is showing a strange behaviour :

```
int main()
{
    char numArr[] = {'9','8','5'};
    int num;
    printf("%d\n",num);
    num = atoi(numArr);
    printf("%d\n",num);
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't initialized the `num` so it contains a garbage value (`51` in my case) and when I store the return value of `atoi()` in num the garbage is **overwritten** and it gets the value returned by `atoi` appended by `3` (the char for `51`) so the output after conversion is `9853` instead of `985`.

It also shows correct behaviour if I initialize num with any value and no appendant is seen.

- If I try it in [ideone](http://ideone.com/aSsK1s) it gets correct results(because they initialize num automatically with 0), but works undesirably in code::blocks on my machine.

I want to know why the garbage value is being appended to return value ?

Comment: Undefined Behavior is Undefined Behavior. Btw you have 2 sources of UB: uninintialized num and no null terminating string passed as argument to atoi

Answer (score 5):

> I want to know why the garbage value is being appended to return value
>   ?

Because appending the garbage value to the return value is a valid behavior of Undefined Behavior.

More general: a program with Undefined Behavior doesn't have a – you guest it – defined behavior. That is the program can crash, can output **anything**, can output and crash, can output and not end... you get the point.

---

Btw you have 2 sources of UB:

- accessing uninitialized variable `num` and
- no null terminating string passed as argument to `atoi`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `atoi` expects a null-terminated string, so it scans until gets one, and it by chance happens so that there's a `'3'`.

Try:

```
char numArr[] = {'9','8','5', 0};
```

Comment: Then it gives 98503, then again the "chance" happens?

Comment: @BigO `{'9','8','5', 0}` is advised, not `{'9','8','5', '0'}` or more simply `char numArr[] = "985"` and in this case the compiler adds the terminating `0`.

Comment: If I use {'9','8','5', 7} , then the 7 is meant as null ? As the output then is 985.

Comment: No, your `{'9','8','5', 7}` is still an unterminated array, therefore it is not in the string format required by `atoi`.

Comment: @BigO char with value `7` is a non-numeric character, so atoi stops on it, but it is still an 'undefined behavior', only this time it is closer to what you want